# UITableViewCell as Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using an `UITableViewCell` to show `UIActivityViewController` but the problem is that once I've clicked the cell the `UIActivityViewController` doesn't appear until I click other cell 3 times or until I click a cell that shows another ViewController, here is when it appears but in the new ViewController and I want it in the same ViewController where the cell is.

The cell that I want to show `UIActivityViewController` is in a `TableViewController`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForCell:self.shareCell]]) {
    NSString *shareText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text to share"];
    NSArray *shareObject = @[shareText];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareObject applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

}

I have an `IBOutlet` for `UITableViewCell` in my .h file implemented in .m.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling wrong method. This is getting called when cell is de-selected

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Use this instead:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, I feel so dumb haha, thank you again!